# Understand Angular 8 routing

Tags: angular, routes

Trying to get familiar with Angular I adapted a sample ([cornflourblue](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/26/angular-8-basic-http-authentication-tutorial-example)) I found in the internet.
It consists of a controlling AppComponent, a LoginComponent and a HomeComponent.
The routing is defined this way:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { LoginComponent } from './login';   

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

But it makes no difference whether I use the URL: localhost:4200, localhost:4200/home or localhost:4200/login - I always see the page defined with **login.component.html**.

The AppCpmponent is this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

The LoginComponent is this (I have removed all logic to keep it simple):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Credentials } from '@app/_models';

@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html' 
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
loginForm: FormGroup;
loading = false;
submitted = false;
returnUrl: string;
error = '';

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
) {     }

ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        username: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
}

// convenience getter for easy access to form fields
get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }
    this.loading = true;           
}

getCredentials(aUsername: string, aPassword: string) {
    let credentials: Credentials = {username :aUsername, password : aPassword};
    console.log("Entered credentials: User=" + credentials.username + " User=" + credentials.password);
    return credentials;

}
```

}

This is the HomeComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '@app/_models';
import { UserService } from '@app/services';

@Component({ templateUrl: 'home.component.html' })
export class HomeComponent {
    loading = true;
    users: User[];
}
```

And this are the used htmls:
app.component.html

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Authentication</span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>        
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <app-login>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </app-login>
</div>
```

home.component.html

```
<div class="card mt-4">
    <h4 class="card-header">You're logged in with Angular 8 & Basic HTTP Authentication!!</h4>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h6>Users from secure api end point</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-5">
    <div class="card">
        <h4 class="card-header">Angular 8 Basic Auth Login Example</h4>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                    Login
                </button>
                <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger mt-3 mb-0">{{error}}</div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the basic index.html is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Authentication</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.1/material.indigo-orange.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I spent already many hours trying to reduce the code, change it an read docs - but could not manage to get a see the HomeComponent - but could not get any further. Appreciate your help

Comment: Why do you have your `router-outlet` *inside* an `app-login` component in the *app.component.html*? That could be the issue.

Comment: As Richards say is the "app.component" who must has the `<router-outlet>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in app.component.html wrong code.

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Authentication</span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>        
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Coppy and paste this code.

If You want your HomeComponent to be on main page like www.sadaasd.com/ in router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',  component: HomeComponent }, // empty path
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

And when You have a component declared as a route do not use anywhere `<app-login>` tag `<router-outlet>` decide when to display it.

Example `bobo.com/home` in `app.component.html` in place of `<router-outlet>` angular will display `home.component.html` when `bobo.com/login` there will be `login.component.html`. This is acording to `path: 'home'` and `path: 'login'`

Comment: I started with an empty path in the "Routes", then I had both the empty path and the "home"-path directing to the HomeComponent to allow for specifying the urls ../home.  You are right, the app.component.html is wrong in so far, that the navigation for "home" would direct to a wrong path - but for my sample this is not of any interest - I do not click the link.

But you are right with the <app-login>-tag, this must not be set in the app.component.html. I changed it and am now fighting with a different error. Thanks a lot